# How to pass object in CLI in corda projects

Tags: corda

I was trying to run car insurance project in corda but but i am not able to know how to pass the claimInfo data in object type can any one help me

https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/carinsurance-QueryableState

i am trying to pass the data like this

```
start InsuranceClaimInitiator claimInfo: {claimNumber: "aa",claimDescription: "rrrr", claimAmount: 9}, policyNumber: "aaa"
```

is this right or should we need to pass differently ????

its showing me this error

```
Wed Feb 19 16:34:55 IST 2020>>> flow start InsuranceClaimFlow$InsuranceClaimInitiator claimInfo: {claimNmuber: "c001",claimDescription: "hello",claimAmount: 123}, policyNumber: "hello"
No matching constructor found:
- [class net.corda.examples.carinsurance.flows.ClaimInfo, class java.lang.String]: Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `net.corda.examples.carinsurance.flows.ClaimInfo` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]





Wed Feb 19 16:35:16 IST 2020>>> flow start InsuranceClaimFlow$InsuranceClaimInitiator {claimInfo: {claimNmuber: "c001",claimDescription: "hello",claimAmount: 123}}, policyNumber: "hello"
flow start InsuranceClaimFlow$InsuranceClaimInitiator {claimInfo: {claimNmuber: "c001",claimDescription: "hello",claimAmount: 123}}, policyNumber: "hello": exception: Expected a field name (Scalar value in YAML), got this instead: <org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.MappingStartEvent(anchor=null, tag=null, implicit=true)>
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 4]
Wed Feb 19 16:36:00 IST 2020>>> [ERROR] 16:36:00+0530 [pool-8-thread-5] command.CRaSHSession. - Error while evaluating request 'flow start InsuranceClaimFlow$InsuranceClaimInitiator {claimInfo: {claimNmuber: "c001",claimDescription: "hello",claimAmount: 123}}, policyNumber: "hello"' flow start InsuranceClaimFlow$InsuranceClaimInitiator {claimInfo: {claimNmuber: "c001",claimDescription: "hello",claimAmount: 123}}, policyNumber: "hello": exception: Expected a field name (Scalar value in YAML), got this instead: <org.yaml.snakeyaml.events.MappingStartEvent(anchor=null, tag=null, implicit=true)>
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 4] [errorCode=rc1dem, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/rc1dem]
```

Comment: This seems to be correct, is there a problem with it?

Comment: it is showing me this error as mention above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a default constructor to the ClaimInfo and it should work fine. Also mark the parameterized constructor with @ConstructorForDeserialization. It requires a default constructor to deserialize.

```
public ClaimInfo(){
    this.claimNumber = null;
    this.claimDescription = null;
    this.claimAmount = 0;
}

@ConstructorForDeserialization
public ClaimInfo(String claimNumber, String claimDescription, int claimAmount) {
    this.claimNumber = claimNumber;
    this.claimDescription = claimDescription;
    this.claimAmount = claimAmount;
}
```

I think we should update this in the sample, or better you could make a PR if you wish.

Comment: I noticed you had a typo "claimNmuber". Did you correct this ?

Comment: Yes i have corrected the typo but still same error can anyone run this project at their end and see if it is working or not.

Comment: so after adding the default constructor the code is working